# Compile linux kernel module for Ubuntu Phone

Tags: kernel, ubuntu-touch

I would like to test a little selfmade kernel module on my Ubuntu Phone.
Can anyone tell me, where i can get the kernel headers to compile?
Or is there something special to know for kernel modules on Ubuntu Touch?

My plan was to cross-compile the kernel module and transfer it to my phone, that I can insmod it via the command line app.

Thanks,
micha